# What does ArrayList<Class<? extends... mean in Java

Tags: java

I suspect it means that the sortedSourceClasses arrayList can contain any class that extends the ReferenceSource class. Is that correct?

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends ReferenceSource>> sortedSourceClasses = new ArrayList<Class<? extends ReferenceSource>>
```

Comment: Pretty much, I would recommend you read up on Generics.

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: Also, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_upper_bounded.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the basic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have 4 classes: `A`, `B`, `C` extending `ReferenceSource` and some unrelated class `D`.
If you use the list from your question you can add `Class` objects to that list, just like this:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends ReferenceSource>> sortedSourceClasses = new ArrayList<Class<? extends ReferenceSource>>;
sortedSourceClasses.add(A.class);
sortedSourceClasses.add(B.class);
sortedSourceClasses.add(C.class);
sortedSourceClasses.add(D.class); // <-- won't work
```

Comment: please extend your answer